# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I tried to get the list of data but I am getting null from `GetAllList()` method. In this project I am using .Net core with ORM Entity Framework core code first approach with repository pattern

Entity class

```cs
public class SIDGenerator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TrackId { get; set; }
    public string Track { get; set; }
    public string SId { get; set; }
    public int InstanceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }
    public bool IsOtherSysType { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeployed { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
   
    public DateTime ReservationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsManuallyDefined { get; set; }
    public int ReservatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Interface

```cs
public interface ISidGeneratorRepository<T> where T :SIDGenerator
{
    T GetById(int id);

    /// <returns>List of the entity</returns>
    List<T> GetAllList();
}
```

Implementation

```cs
public class SidGeneratorRepository<T> : ISidGeneratorRepository<T> where T : SIDGenerator
{
    private readonly SHIELDDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ILoggerManager _logger;
    private readonly IDateTime _date;
    public SidGeneratorRepository(SHIELDDbContext dbContext, ILoggerManager logger, IDateTime date)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _logger = logger;
        _date = date;
    }
 
    public void Delete(SIDGenerator entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DeleteById(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<T> GetAllList()
    {
        var result= _dbContext.Set<T>()//This statement causes exception data is null
               .ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        var sid = _dbContext.Set<T>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        if (sid == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException("Sid could not be found with id " + id.ToString(), id);
        }

        return sid;
    }
}
```

This is my dbcontext class

```cs
public class SHIELDDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SHIELDDbContext(DbContextOptions<SHIELDDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SIDGenerator> SIDGenerator { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserRoleSeedConfig).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Below is my handler class

```cs
public Task<GetAllSidViewModel> Handle(GetAllSidQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        
        var sidList = _sidRepository.GetAllList();
        if (sidList?.Count > 0)
        {
            var viewModel = new GetAllSidViewModel
            {
                sIDlist = sidList
            };
            return Task.FromResult(viewModel);
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Could not retrieve SID LIST from DB" + ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is the table script for the above Entity

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SIDGenerator](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Track] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TrackId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InstanceNumber] [int] NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InUse] [bit] NULL,
    [IsOtherSysType] [bit] NULL,
    [IsDeployed] [bit] NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ReservationDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReservatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [IsManuallyDefined] [bit] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SIDGenerators] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: In your model almost all fields are nullable, it is required? If yes, correct your model, for example `DateTime? ReservationDate`. Or configure your model properly.

Comment: no all fields are not required except Id property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model like this, or configure nullable properties by your wish.

```
public class SIDGenerator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TrackId { get; set; }
    public string Track { get; set; }
    public string SId { get; set; }
    public int? InstanceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool? InUse { get; set; }
    public bool? IsOtherSysType { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeployed { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
   
    public DateTime? ReservationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsManuallyDefined { get; set; }
    public int? ReservatedBy { get; set; }
}
```